# oracle sum error Difference in plural in query

Tags: oracle, plsql

Difference in plural in query
When querying or querying inside a variable, different results appear

```
select  /* get sum Item */  
                  nvl(sum(p.price_main * (p.quantity+p.free_qty)),0) SumItMain,
                  nvl(sum(p.price_stok * (p.quantity+p.free_qty)),0)SumItStok
                  from  purchases_bill_details p
                  where p.header_id=1
```

```
SumItMain 22020000
SumItStok 36700
```

[image]

```
declare 
    SumItMain float;
    SumItStok float;
begin
      select  /* get sum Item */  
                    nvl(sum(p.price_main * (p.quantity+p.free_qty)),0),
                  nvl(sum(p.price_stok * (p.quantity+p.free_qty)),0)
                   into  SumItMain, SumItStok
                  from  purchases_bill_details p
                  where p.header_id=1 ;
                     dbms_output.put_line(SumItMain);
                     dbms_output.put_line(SumItStok);
end;

    SumItMain 22019999.99999999999999999999999999999991
    SumItStok 36699.9999999999999999999999999999999999
```

[image]

I want to return the same query values in variables

Comment: Something you must keep in mind. Your looking for nice neat values in base 10 arithmetic from a device that operates in base 2.  The problem is that representing decimal values be  exactly in binary is almost impossible. You often have to make adjustments as Littlefoot suggests or use *[trunc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRUNC-number.html#GUID-911AE7FE-E04A-471D-8B0E-9C50EBEFE07D)(value, places)* where places is the number of digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like rounding problem. Use

```
dbms_output.put_line(round(SumItMain));
dbms_output.put_line(round(SumItStok));
```